# Obligation to subscribe to Jewish Newspapers?

Tags: sources-mekorot, home-house

While listening to a recorded shiur from a long time ago, the Rav mentioned a Peleh Yoetz who says every Jewish home should subscribe to a Jewish newspaper in order to know the news of the Jewish people to daven for anyone who needs help.

Where is this Peleh Yoetz?

Comment: It's probably not relevant anymore with the internet

Comment: Can’t remember where it is but doesn’t the Rambam day something to the effect of one who doesn’t join in with the sufferings of the Jewish people is ... (something bad)?